# How would I prepare a table of the top 15 movies using their names and average ratings?

Tags: python

Before reading this I am extremely new to coding so many things I am going to ask are cringe.

I am using http://www.d2l.ai/chapter_recommender-systems/movielens.html and trying to use that dataset to grow my coding skills. I am coding in Python's Spyder.

What I was wondering was what if I was the CEO and wanted to know what the top 15 movies were by Name and Ratings given by users. This is simple enough for an intermediate coder but mind you I am the lowest a beginner can be. The code I have used so far is copy paste what they have done on that link in order to upload the file into Python.

My Mindset: I believe my next steps would be to create a DataFrame using Pandas and somehow use a value count. I am searching things up online and its throwing a bunch of info at me like Jaccard Similarities and Distances. I don't know if this type of question requires such a setup.

Any Help would be loved and if you do respond I may ask more questions out of curiosity.

Comment: If as you say you are `extremely new to coding`, you should go through https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ and then write code without copy pasting. You can solve your problem with simple maps and arithmetic. That would be much more helpful than using pandas or any similarity algos at this point.

Comment: My problem is I enrolled in a course and I was given this website to "Explore" so I am taking it upon myself to use what I have been given as my own take-home work. Since the course expects stuff like that from me I kind of need to understand the more intermediate process. It's not for school its just a nightly course offered by my community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have downloaded [ml-100k.zip](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip) and store it somewhere.

```py
# Read user rating data as dataframe
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, 'u.data'), '\t', names=['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])

# Since you want the average rating of each movie,
# you can group by `item_id` which represent each movie.
# After groupby, do a mean operation on each group.
# Also you want the ratings higher at first,
# you can sort on `rating` column discending
average_rating = data.groupby('item_id', as_index=False)['rating'].mean().sort_values('rating', ascending=False)

# Read move data as dataframe
item = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, 'u.item'), '|', names=['movie id', 'movie title', 'release date', 'video release date', 'IMDb URL', 'unknown', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children\'s', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Documentary', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Film-Noir', 'Horror', 'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'War', 'Western'])

# Load movie title from u.item to average_rating
average_rating['movie_title'] = average_rating['item_id'].map(item.set_index('movie id')['movie title'])
```

Since some movies are rated by only a small number of people, you may need to filter them first.